# How to evaluate the limit of a function consists of Range

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I would like to evaluate the limit:
$$
\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\sqrt{4+\sqrt{5+\cdots}}}}}
$$
Therefore, I write the following function of n:

```
g[p_, n_] := Sqrt[p] + n;
f[n_] := Sqrt[Fold[g, 0, Reverse@Range@n]],
```

and evaluate the limit:

```
Limit[f[n], n -> Infinity].
```

But Mathematica said:

```
Range::range: "Range specification in Range[n] does not have appropriate bounds."
```

Is there something wrong with my code?
How can i make this work?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: (1) `Limit` operates on continuous parameters only. It sometimes "works" for functions of a discrete parameter (sequences) but only if they accidently have definitions in terms of a continuous parameter that give the same limiting behavior.

Comment: (2) `Limit` has absolutely no capability to handle what amounts to a program, e.g. `f[n_]:=...` where the ... part is computed by an iterative algorithm (e.g. using a function such as `Fold` or `Nest`).

Comment: (3) I would surmise this is a difficult problem to do using Mathematica other than in an approximation approach. So it is an interesting question.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau  Thanks，I finally know why it is difficult to calculate this limit of the sequence in Mathematica.

Comment: It does print infinity...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see that:

```
Fold[Sqrt[#1 + #2] &, 0, Reverse@Range[7]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

is the [Kasner number](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2301294) - - [OEIS link with many references](http://oeis.org/A072449)

```
DiscretePlot[Fold[Sqrt[#1 + #2] &, 0, Reverse@Range[i]], {i, 50}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I understand your idea is to calculation the function for large n instead of evaluate the limit itself. Does that mean there is no way to evaluate this limit directly in Mathematica?

Comment: @robit Well, it's the Kasner number. See [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2301294).

Comment: @robit You can find more info on the convergence of those series [**here**](http://books.google.com/books?id=TT1T8A94xNcC&pg=PA221) ... those problems were Ramanujan's pets

Comment: Thanks, I get it. These are very good references for sequences like this!